# prevent user login after registration using django-allauth

Tags: django-allauth

i'm using django-allauth for my django app. by default, when a user successfully sign's up, they are automatically logged in. how do you override the default behaviour and prevent the user from logging in after  after successful signup. After the user signs up, he/she must be redirected to the login page. ive disabled email verification. Thank you.

```
# settings.py
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'welcome'
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATED_LOGIN_REDIRECTS = False
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'thanks'

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'none'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need the email verification, you can skip the login like this:

First in your **urls.py**, you must override the url to the default SignupView with a url to your own view:

```
url(r^'accounts/signup/$', views.CustomSignupView.as_view(), name="account_signup")
```

Then in your **views.py**, you have a custom view that will return a path to your frontpage instead of continuing to login the user.

```
class CustomSignupView(SignupView):

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.user = form.save(self.request)
        return redirect('/frontpage')
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did to prevent auto-login during signup was to modify/override `DefaultAccountAdapter.pre_login`.

The signup view calls a function called `process_login` which in turn calls adapter functions including `pre_login` and `post_login`.

Here is the code flow/path I'm referring to:

1. `SignupView.form_valid`: https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/main/allauth/account/views.py#L260-L265
2. `complete_signup` calls `perform_login`: https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/main/allauth/account/utils.py#L243-L250
3. `perform_login` checks `adapter.pre_login`: https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/main/allauth/account/utils.py#L178

So you can implement your own version of `DefaultAccountAdapter.pre_login` to add any logical checks you want.

In our case, we only continue w/ auto login in the case where the signing up user's email address is marked as verified ahead of time.

Otherwise, since the user still needs to verify their email address, we do not log them in.

We did this in order to prevent any sort of account enumeration, but note that doing this likely breaks the behavior of the [`ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION`](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/account/configuration.html?highlight=ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION#configuration) setting, since that feature relies on matching the issued `sessionid` cookie after registration against what is submitted when the user loads the email verification link in that same browser.