# Django Allauth Signup Prevent Login

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

Is there anyway to prevent the Allauth Signup form from automatically logging in the User?

I found a similar post here with no answers:

[prevent user login after registration using django-allauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50568209/prevent-user-login-after-registration-using-django-allauth)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get logged in because this behavior is baked into the signup view of the allauth. When the form is valid, the view calls the function called `complete_signup` that does two things:

1. Emits the `user_signed_up` signal
2. Logs a user in

To solve this, we need to leave the step 1 and replace the step 2 with a simple redirect.

Here's how this can be done:

1. Extend the SignupView from `allauth/account/views.py` and override its `form_valid` method like this:

   ```
   class CustomSignupView(SignupView):
       def form_valid(self, form):
           # By assigning the User to a property on the view, we allow subclasses
           # of SignupView to access the newly created User instance
           self.user = form.save(self.request)
           try:
               signals.user_signed_up.send(
                   sender=self.user.__class__,
                   request=self.request,
                   user=self.user, 
                   **{}
               )
               return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
           except ImmediateHttpResponse as e:
               return e.response
   ```

   Haven't tested the code, but it should be working.
2. Wire your new view up in urls.py, so it replaces the old Signup view url.

Comment: If you're using confirmation email you also need to call `allauth.account.utils.send_email_confirmation`.

Comment: Also note that the function to send verification email is included in pre_login function so if you do this the verification email might disappear

Answer (score 0):

I am using django-allauth 0.42.0

There is no need to extend the SignUp view, it can be achieved by the setting:

```
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'
```

in your project settings.py file.

Comment: Needless to say a side effect of this is that user cannot login at all until email is verified, which might or might not be desired.