# django-allauth: letting user complete all steps for signing up but prevent login

Tags: django

Is it possible to configure django-allauth such that a user can proceed to verify emails after signing up, but not log in until I manually enable the account in the Admin site?

Background: I will be releasing an app on the Internet but I don't want everyone to start using it. I want to manage the number of users logging in just in case my website is crashed. The server is hosted on AWS. I'm not sure if this is a good strategy. Should I start autoload balancing from day 1?

Possible duplicates:
[Django Allauth Signup Prevent Login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50893917/django-allauth-signup-prevent-login)
Conflicting answers - one is saying I don't need to extend the SignUp view and another has the extension.

[prevent user login after registration using django-allauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50568209/prevent-user-login-after-registration-using-django-allauth)
The answer is for cases where email verification is not needed.

Comment: Before looking for a solution it may be worth checking to see if you have a problem that needs to be addressed. You could create some load tests to get a sense of what your site can handle by default. Then using django_debug_toolbar to see if you can improve your initial numbers.

Comment: @EdKohler how do I simulate 100 vs. 10,000 users logging in and running the business logic?

Comment: here's an explanation. https://www.loadview-testing.com/blog/aws-load-testing-load-balancing-best-practices/